# Animating from a point other than the left side

Tags: wpf, animation

I have an animation problem that I'm not sure how to Google or find a solution for. I'm trying to basically create a wrapping Marquee. I do this by having the following within a canvas:

|---Section A---|---Section B---|Section C---|

The animation begins with the left side of section B on the right side of the screen, and ends when the right side of section B hits the left side of the screen. Sections A and C are a mirror image of Section B, which creates the "wrap around" effect. When the animation ends, I move everything to the right the exact width of Section B. To the user, nothing appears to have happened .. it's all just wrapping around.

The problem is this ... some of the items in the marquee can be hidden, or can change size. So if you hide an item, the item is hidden from all three sections. Since things are being hidden in Section A, and all the sections are sized dynamically, the entire marquee moves to the left.

Is there any way to "anchor" the animation at a spot, say, in the middle of Section B, so that when items are hidden in section A, it doesn't slide sections B and C over? Instead, I want Section A to move right to fill in the space.

Edit: Let me rephrase ... because this is confusing.

I have a canvas, which contains a stackpanel, which contains three more stack panels. These three stack panels are actually copies of the same information, which gives the illusion of a marquee that wraps around when I animate. When items are added/removed in the marquee, those items in the stack panel change, which adjusts the overall size of the stack panel, which adjusts the size of the canvas. What I'd like to know, is if I can "anchor" a specific location within the stackpanel. Can I "anchor" on the first item in the 2nd stackpanel copy?

Answer (score 1):

To answer what APPEARS to be the primary question:

> Is there a way to animation the position of a canvas using something
>   other than the Canvas.Left property

Set the `RenderTransform` property of the `Canvas` to a `TranslateTransform` and animate the `TranslateTransform.X` Property:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="0"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>  
</Canvas>
```

Then in code:

EDIT: The second parameter of this method call should be of type `DoubleAnimation`, not `Duration`. I must have been sleeping at my desk when I typed this. Sorry.

```
(TranslateTransform)MyCanvas.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does. Can't believe I've gotten this far without learning rendertransformorigin. Is there a way to anchor on a specific point within a control though, rather than a percentage? For example, if I want to anchor on a specific control that might move around since the controls surrounding it can change size. I'd like it so that when the marquee changes size, whatever is on the screen at the time stays on the screen, instead of moving right or left. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you share your markup? `Canvas` children shouldn't move around at all when other items are added or removed. You must have another layout panel handling the position inside the `Canvas` to be experiencing what you describe. 

Please post some markup so we can continue to help. Thanks.

Comment: I could have explained this better. I have a canvas, which contains a stackpanel, which contains three more stack panels. These three stack panels are actually copies of the same information, which gives the illusion of a marquee that wraps around when I animate. When items are added/removed in the marquee, those items in the stack panel change, which adjusts the overall size of the stack panel, which adjusts the size of the canvas. What I'd like to know, is if I can "anchor" a specific location within the stackpanel. Can I "anchor" on the first item in the 2nd stackpanel copy?

Comment: Also, I tried setting the RenderTransformOrigin. When the marquee re-sizes, it still doesn't re-size out from the middle. Everything moves relative to the left side.

Comment: I am still not exactly sure what you`re asking, but let me try pointing out a couple of things that might help:

Comment: 1) If you have a list of elements in a StackPanel, and you set the Visibility of any of those elements to Collapsed, the other items will shift as the StackPanel Arrange method is called. If you want to mitigate this behavior within a StackPanel, you can set Visibility of child elements to Hidden, and the StackPanel will preserve the layout space of the invisible element...but your marquee will now have blank areas where they once were Not sure if that is desired results for you, but that is really your only option within StackPanel. 2) A better panel for your needs as I can tell is Canvas.

Comment: All child elements of Canvas are positioned relative to the top, left corner of the Canvas, according to Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left attached property values. Therefore the position of any element within the Canvas is not dependent at all upon any other child's position or visibility. These comments are getting lengthy, and if you need any more help you are going to have to post some code with clear expectations for desired behavior, and we will move this over to chat as SO suggests. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also, one more thing. Instead of duplicating elements across multiple stackpanels, may I suggest using just 1 container for the visuals and a VisualBrush for each of the replications? This will result in less overhead for the renderer and a more consistant experience for you the developer and the user. Just a suggestion. I hope this helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20628/discussion-between-craig-and-xamlzealot)

Answer (score 1):

My other answer is becoming obsolete as you elaborate on your desired behavior, so forgive me for posting a second. Based on my latter comments on the above answer, consider the following example:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid x:Name="MarqueePanels">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=PrimaryMarquee, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=PrimaryMarquee, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=PrimaryMarquee}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PrimaryMarquee">
            <TextBlock Text="Marquee Item 1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Marquee Item 2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Marquee Item 3"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Height="{Binding ElementName=PrimaryMarquee, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=PrimaryMarquee, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=PrimaryMarquee}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

    </Grid>

</Canvas>
```

As I mentioned above, setting the `Visibility` of any of the `TextBox` elements to `Hidden` will not cause the `StackPanel` parent to resize, however using `Visibility.Collapsed` WILL force an `Arrange` pass of the parent panel. So if you truly NEED to use a `StackPanel` to contain the visual elements, then I recommend based on your comments above using `Visibility.Hidden` in lieu of `Visibility.Collapsed`.

Also notice the use of `VisualBrush` to replicate the Marquee content. This will simplify the code, and ensure that all 3 visuals always match (with the exception of whatever positioning or transformation you apply to the `Rectangle` objects that house the `VisualBrush`).

Additionally, I should say that I personally would use a `Canvas` in lieu of the `StackPanel`, as the `Canvas` is much better suited for absolute positioning of child elements, hence the reason for your question.

Craig, I truly hope this helps. I (like most people on here) will try to help however I can. Good luck!

Comment: It helped me learn some new stuff about WPF, but I don't think it solves my problem. Visual Brush removes functionality I need in the marquee ... IE, the ability to click. Visibility.Hidden isn't what I want either ... I need the items to collapse. I just need the items to collapse inward. I have everything about the ticker working, except for what happens when an item in the marquee changes size (removed, added, changed, etc). Everything moves left

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

I set the margin to -(theControl.ActualWidth / 2). All my code shifts everything back by that same amount to compensate.

Then I have an event handler for SizeChanged on the control, where I set this value. If the size of the control changes, the margin is update, and everything focuses on the middle of the control. If you have a specific point within the control that you want to center animation on, then use that point instead of the halfway point described above.